# Which endpoints are supported for OAuth2 token authorization?

Tags: rest-api, rest, oauth2, oauth

Documentation says that for OAuth2 token authorization URL like login.salesforce.com should be used

```
For authorization: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize
For token requests: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
For revoking OAuth tokens: https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/revoke
```

However, documentation doesn't tell anything about which other URL could be used for sandboxes and if lightning domain URL can be used for this?

For example, when I try to connect to https://domain--full.lightning.force.com/services/oauth2/token I receive `unsupported_grant_type` error response

Comment: "it is now clear"? That sounds like a typo.

Comment: Updated to "However, documentation doesn't tell anything about which other URL could be used for sandboxes"

Answer (score 2):

For sandboxes two URL types can be used:

1. Generic URL like https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token
2. Specific Classic Domain URL like https://domain--full.cs100.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

Lightning domain URL cannot be used.

Classic domain URL changes every refresh since Sandbox might migrate to another instance, so it is better to use always Generic URL

Comment: For MyDomain, I think it depends on the sequence of when mydomain was established; if you applied my domain to an existing sandbox, then the URL looks like `https://domain--full.cs100.my.salesforce.com`; if the sandbox came from PROD, then it would be `https://domain--featureBox.my.salesforce.com` _(no ref to a pod)_

Comment: I have refreshed sandbox from production, and it has the instance name in the classic URL

Comment: What do you get if you create a new sandbox from Prod?

Answer (score 0):

https://test.salesforce.com/... is the right way to go for sandboxes.

From the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm&type=5)

> Instead of login.salesforce.com, customers can also use the My Domain,
>   community, or test.salesforce.com (sandbox) domains in these
>   endpoints.

(Admittedly, it's a very brief doc note)